# Rails3 + Rspec2 + Factorygirl association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rspec2, factory-bot

I have the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   
     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company_id
end


 class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :email, :name
 end


#test/factories/companies.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name "sample company"
    email "sample@company.com"
  end
end

#test/factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do |u|
   u.email 'sameera@sample.com'
   u.password 'welcome'
   u.password_confirmation 'welcome'
   u.association :company, :factory => :company
 end
end


#spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
 
describe User do
   describe "Validations" do
     it "should validate the email" do
       user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => nil)
       user.should have(1).error_on(:email)
     end
   end
end
```

but I'm getting this error, with guard (even after re-starting Guard)

```
15:47:35 - INFO - Running: spec/models/user_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/sameera/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-rspec-2.4.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec/models/user_spec.rb"]...
F

Failures:

  1) User Validations should validate the email
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, :email => nil)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `company=' for #<User:0x00000004dcee08>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16308 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5 # User Validations should validate the email


Randomized with seed 26095

Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User` model doesn't declare a belongs_to association as you factory assume it would:

you should add it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company_id
  belongs_to :company
end
```

of course this assumes that your user table has a `company_id` column (but I guess you already added it, as you listed it in attr_accessible)

Comment: this worked:) thanks, silly me. I was trying to test the association next LOL :), thanks again

Comment: and by the way, for the kid of tests you're doing, you should have a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda . Among other cool features, it allows you to write `it { should validate_presence_of(:password)}`